# Derivation of the following function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

We know that if $\sin x$ is positive, then $\sin x\le 1$. So $\ln(\sin x)$ is negative. Hence the domain of  $f(x)=\sqrt{\ln(\sin x)}$ is $\{2k\pi+\pi/2;k\in \Bbb Z\}$. Therefore  $\operatorname{Int}(D_{f})=\emptyset$. Now by Wolfram Alpha $$f'(x)=\frac{\cot x}{2\sqrt{\ln(\sin x)}}.$$ Is there a contradiction or my reasoning wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not specify the used field with wolframalpha.  If the field is not $\mathbb{R}$ but $\mathbb{C}$, then the logarithm, the sine and the square roots are all holomorphic functions with (most of) $\mathbb{C}$ as their entire domain.

Thus worlframalpha is right to do the standard computations, in case you needed the result in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Isn't there still a branch cut along the $x<0$ real negative numbers?

Comment: There is a cut but it can be any axis half-line starting from the origin.  The most funny thing is that the cut doesn't cause any trouble to compute the derivative.  If you rotate the cut away, any possible result for the logarithm locally with still give the same derivative.  Read wikipedia for more details : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm

Comment: Check,  forgot how the inverse function theorem would apply.  I did horribly in multivariable analysis, really need to go over that subject again when I'm not studying for my algebra qual.   +1 )

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Wolfram|Alpha probably just computed the derivative using the standard derivation rules, but even then we have that
$$\operatorname{dom}(f') = \emptyset$$

So the derivative is pointless (over the reals).

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram Alpha's is a formal answer, obtained by manipulation of symbols and systematic rules. It does not check if the function is defined.